# Getting a sum from Parse with Parse Cloud Code (for iOS app)

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm new to Parse Cloud Code and am struggling with a seemingly simple task.

I'm working on a small iOS game where the users can choose from a list of characters to play -- imagine mario or luigi.  In addition to tracking user scores in the game, I'm tracking total points for each character in Parse, so I can display a "mario" total and a "luigi" total (from all users.)

There could be multiple users playing at once (I hope), so I don't have Parse saving to just one mario and one luigi counter.  Instead, each user gets a running count of their own mario and luigi scores.

So how do I pull the total marioPoints and total luigiPoints?

Parse doesn't have SQL-styled querying, so I've been looking at Parse Cloud Code and their "average stars" example (https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code) looked kind of close at first glance:

But I can't get it sorted.  And even if I could, it's limited to 1,000 responses, which wouldn't be enough.  (I'm optimistic.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to keep a running total when any individual user update is saved. Do that using a save hook and the `increment( attr, amount )` function.